# Issue with script returning $null in Pester test while it shouldn't

Tags: powershell, pester

So I'm having a bit of an issue in PowerShell
I wrote a simple script for a class project about Pester testing
It looks like this

```
param ([Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$FN, [Parameter(Mandatory)]$OP, [Parameter()]$SN)

$solution

try {
    if ($OP -eq '+') {

        $solution = ([long]($FN) + [long]($SN))
    
    }

    elseif ($OP -eq '-') {

        $solution = ([long]($FN) - [long]($SN))
    
    }

    elseif ($OP -eq '*') {

        $solution = ([long]($FN) * [long]($SN))
    
    }

    elseif ($OP -eq '/') {

        if ($SecondNumber -eq 0) {
            $solution = "Cannot divide by 0";
        }

        $solution = ([long]($FN) / [long]($SN))
    
    }

    elseif ($OP -eq 'V') {
        $solution = ([math]::Sqrt($FN))
    
    }
    
    else {
        $solution = "Not a valid operator"
    }
    
}
catch {
    Write-Output "An error occured"
}

return $solution
```

Now this all works fine and when i go into the console and run it with ooutput going into a variable it works fine.

```
PS C:\PowerShellProject> $test = .\Script.ps1 1 + 1
PS C:\PowerShellProject> $test
2
```

But then when i run this Pester test

```
Describe "Test for Script.ps1" {
    Context "Testing calculations" {
        It "+ test" {
            $plus = .\Test.ps1 -FN 2 -OP + -SN 2
            $plus | Should -Be 4
        }
    }
}
```

It returns the following

```
PS C:\PowerShellProject> Invoke-Pester .\Test.ps1

Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 1 tests in 15ms.
Running tests.

[-] Test for Script.ps1.Testing calculations.+ test 18ms (16ms|2ms)
 Expected 4, but got $null.
 at $plus | Should -Be 4, C:\PowerShellProject\Test.ps1:6
 at <ScriptBlock>, C:\PowerShellProject\Test.ps1:6
[-] Context Test for Script.ps1.Testing calculations failed
 InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Tests completed in 156ms
Tests Passed: 0, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 1
BeforeAll \ AfterAll failed: 1
  - Test for Script.ps1.Testing calculations
```

I'm still pretty new to Powershell so I must probably be making a silly mistake here.

Maybe someone could redirect me to another question that had a similar problem or give me a solution to my problem. This would be really helpful since I have been breaking my head over this for a couple of hours and it's really starting to annoy me.

Comment: Parameter `$OP` should be a string, so use `.\Script.ps1 1 '+' 1`. Also, have a look at using a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) instead of all those `if(){..} elseif() {..}` lines to make your script become much more readable

Comment: @Theo In argument parsing mode, `$OP` argument will be a string, even if unquoted.

Comment: @Theo You are right about using a switch I was doing that before and I thought that that was maybe the issue. But making it a String doesn't change anything for me

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pester, but why do you start your script with the (at that point) undefined variable `$solution`? Is that the `$null` value Pester is complaining about?

Comment: @Theo doesn't change a thing that was one of my troubleshooting steps as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line at the start of your function:

```
$solution
```

This does not declare the variable, as you propably expect, but due to PowerShells implicit output behaviour, it actually *outputs* the variable. The output is `$null` as the variable has not been defined yet.

To actually define the variable you have to assign a value:

```
$solution = 0
```

Later, when you do `return $solution`, you are actually adding another value to the output stream, which when captured to a variable, will be the array `@($null, 2)`.

Proof:

```
$plus = .\Test.ps1 -FN 2 -OP + -SN 2            
Write-Host $plus.GetType().Name
```

This prints `Object[]`, although we would expect `int`.

In PowerShell you usually don't use the `return` statement, except when you want to early exit from a function. `return $solution` is actually just a shortcut for:

```
$solution  # implicit output
return     # exit from function
```

---

There is another issue in your Pester test script, where you are calling the wrong script. It should be:

```
$plus = .\Script.ps1 -FN 2 -OP + -SN 2
```

Comment: I'm still having the same issue even after this solution

Comment: @MichielDeCap When I remove the `$solution` line at the top of the script or replace it by `$solution = 0` the test passes for me. Have you changed something else?

Comment: @MichielDeCap In your pester test script you call `.\Test.ps1`, while it should be `.\Script.ps1`!